# calling modal window from asp.net secure site links

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hello all quick question on having a modal window spawn for a secure asp.net site. I currently have a asp test site setup which when the user clicks on the login link it opens the standard asp.net login page (login.aspx) within a modal telerik RadWindow. I am calling this page using javascript and this works fine.

The challenge I have now is when a user clicks on a link within the page if that link points to a secure section the login screen loads in the main frame of the site vs. a pop-up. I realize why (aka my js funciton is not being called) my question is to work around this would the correct/acceptible approach be to call a method from each link/button that tests for user authenticaiton?  If the user is authenticated then redirect to the page otherwise call the javascript funciton to open the window?

Or can the be done within javascript?

I've been out of asp.net for awhile and I am a bit rusty. Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Okay so I have some progress to now at least determine if the user is validated. Since I am using forsm auth I can test this using ISAUthenticated

```
public void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
       // myalert.Text = "<script language type='text/javascript'> function OpenWin() {var opWin = window.radopen(null, 'RadWindow1');opWin.setUrl(opWin.get_navigateUrl());}</script>";
     }
    else
    {
        myalert.Text = "no dice";
    }
}
```

Now I need to figure out how to invoke the js function from here. Any ideas would be appreciated.
thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, try

```
public void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("myScript", "<script language='javascript'>alert('');</script>");
    }
    else {
        myalert.Text = "no dice";
    }
}
```

However, you should have authentication be checked on a page's load, rather than prior to it. What if someone knows the URL to your secure page and just goes to it directly?

Comment: thanks bitxwise. As far as security I am handling this through my web.config file/aspnet security model. even if they know the URL unless they are authenticated within the site they  can't get access to the directory. (Secure pages are stored within their own directory)